# Google map: apk on Third Party App Markets didn't works VS apk downloaded from Google Play works fine. What should I do?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

It is same `apk` but different result.
When I get the application through the `third party App Markets`, it didn't works.
(It shows only blank page with small google logo on left-bottom side.)
But when I download that apk through `Google Play`, it works fine.
I've checked them as same file.

Is there any genius who can solve this issue??

Comment: What do you mean by "When I get the application through the market"..?

Comment: Are both have same version?

Comment: add your debug Fingerprint SHA key to development console for google map API

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran just down load from android market

Comment: @Shubhamsoni Yeap! absolutely!

Comment: @DamirMailybayev I can't get what you mean.... My problem is on release but you said using debug key.... I can't understand...

Comment: @dalami0i I am little confused Why do you mean by the android market, Google play only right..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran As a beginner, I can't what do you mean exactly... Anyway I put "market " means "Google Play Market". I mean download from the website https://play.google.com/apps/~.

Comment: Why do you need to know the answer?